# MySQL/Hibernate SQLQuery how to cast unsigned int(10) to smallint?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have following sql query

```
final String GET_ASSIGNMENT_STATUS = 
    "select wtd.work_task_detail_id as workTaskDetailId, "
    + "a.code_name as workTaskStatusName, a.code_id as workTaskStatusId, "
    + "from work_task_detail wtd "
    ... JOINS
    + "where wtd.work_task_detail_id = :assignmentId";
assignmentStatus = ( AssignmentStatus ) session.createSQLQuery(GET_ASSIGNMENT_STATUS)
            .setResultTransformer( Transformers.aliasToBean( AssignmentStatus.class ) )
            .setInteger("assignmentId", assignmentId).uniqueResult();
```

In that query I'm selecting  a column `a.code_id as workTaskStatusId` which is **`unsigned int(10)`** inside Database and **`Short`** at Java side.
While executing that query I'm getting exception at **`setterMethod()`** which takes `Short` as input parameter(which I can changed).

but I want to Convert/Cast it at sql side.
How do I cast **`unsigned int(10)`** to **`smallint`** in sql query ?

I tried doing

```
cast(a.code_id as smallint) as workTaskStatusId,
```

but It gave me **sql error** near `smallint`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL you can `CAST` and `CONVERT` to only following types:

- BINARY[(N)]
- CHAR[(N)]
- NCHAR[(N)]
- JSON
- DATE
- DATETIME
- DECIMAL[(M[,D])]
- SIGNED [INTEGER]
- TIME
- UNSIGNED [INTEGER]

... as per [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast).

Comment: Thanks for list, looking at your answer I think my question is duplicate,

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use native Query?

I thing the database and or HQL doesn't know smallint because it's not called smallint for every kind of database. And as it seems you are trying to implement a Query for just a specific kind of Database (like Oracle or something) it's better to use a native Query. You are trying to use a specific function of the database to get it as smallint. Why do you want to achieve this? Isn't it okay to select the value as it is stored in the database? Otherwise maybe it's not storewd right because know you want a smallint and before it was a long. Type conversion is always a critical part of the code.